# MVC javascript file segregation/performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Lets say an MVC3 project has a number of JavaScript files and libraries. These are referenced by a shared layout view, at the bottom of this page. The idea being the page loads faster as the libraries are included after the page main content. There is also no in-line JavaScript in the views.

The project has a number of areas and each has a number of controllers. There is however just 1 JavaScript file that contains all of the custom scripting and events for the whole site. So code unique to a particular controller will be included for all page loads.

Is there a better way to structure the files or to segregate the code so only relevant scripting is executed?

Edit:
So a strategy of splitting 1 large script file, or to only have scripting execute that's relevant to the current context. NO use initializing lots of event handlers for elements that do not exist on a page. Even manually checking if each element exists beforehand is an overhead in site wide file.

Comment: Something like RequireJS might help you: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Isn't RequireJS a way of grouping related libraries together or defining a group of them to load on a single page? Unless of course it can also take a large js file and only load parts that are relevant to the currently executing page.